# Why doesn't JRuby script.rb > out.txt capture Java errors?

Tags: linux, jruby

[JRuby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRuby) script.rb throws many Java errors.

I tried outputting to a text file, but only the output from the script itself is recorded. I need to capture all the errors that happen, as they are very long. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors probably go to the error stream (stderr), not the output stream (stdout). So you need to redirect the error stream into the output stream:

```
script.rb > out.txt 2>&1
```

Or, if you want just the errors:

```
script.rb 2> errors.txt
```